# How to create a random name picker wheel app

Tags: random, generator, picker

I have a random name picker which I’ve made in PowerPoint however I’d like to do this in an app with xCode but I’m not sure how to get the random wheel like it is in this PowerPoint file.
I need it to have a list where the user can enter player names with say a maximum of 100 entries and once the names are entered then go to the wheel and have a button to spin through the names like in this PowerPoint file and randomly select a name from the list of names entered and display it then once this is done show a button to remove that chosen name from the list or just leave it there and prevent the app from selecting the same name again until the app is reset.
Any help here would be hugely appreciated.
Thanks.

https://1drv.ms/p/s!AqV2LEz7-FE63zyRC3chH7PYpPKK?e=g9WF8f

I have tried searching for solutions online but unsure where to start with this one.